Error Mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/ on Ubuntu 24.04
My WD G-Drive connects to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS but receives the error Error Mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/ on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. G-Drive is connected to same port regardless of Distro but 22.04 is running on a separate external NVME whereas 24.04 is running on a partition with Dual boot Internal with W11.

Most common issue is that Windows uses fast startup which sets hibernation flag. Then Linux NTFS driver should not mount NTFS read/write to prevent losing data as hibernation will restore it when booted again with Windows. Windows also turns fast startup back on with some updates. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

This is a known bug on Ubuntu 24.04.
No solution so far: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/2062972
